# Sort an Array of ArrayList<Integer> in java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist, compare

I want to  sort an Array of ArrayList by the first int of the ArrayLists elements. 
I have tried to override the compare method of the Comparator class but it throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at BikeGA$1.compare(BikeGA.java:515)
at BikeGA$1.compare(BikeGA.java:1)
at java.util.TimSort.countRunAndMakeAscending(TimSort.java:351)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:230)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1438)
at BikeGA.main(BikeGA.java:512)
```

The code is:

```
int max_generations = 20;
static ArrayList<Integer>[] population = new ArrayList[max_generations];

Arrays.sort(population, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(final ArrayList<Integer> entry1, final ArrayList<Integer> entry2){
            return entry1.get(0).compareTo(entry2.get(0));
        }
    });
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Post the stack trace please.

Comment: did you initialize all ArrayLists in the array, and added at least an element to each of them?

Comment: Sounds like "entry1" and/or "entry2" is null at somepoint

Comment: Are you sure that all the `ArrayList`s in `population` are initialized?

Comment: Yes, I have printed the array before the sort and it's correctly initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Comparator should handle null or empty `ArrayList`s in order for it to work with any data you put in your array :

```
    @Override
    public int compare(final ArrayList<Integer> entry1, final ArrayList<Integer> entry2){
        if (entry1 == null && entry2 == null)
            return 0;
        if (entry1 == null)
            return 1;
        if (entry2 == null)
            return -1;
        if (entry1.isEmpty() && entry2.isEmpty())
            return 0;
        if (entry1.isEmpty())
            return 1;
        if (entry2.isEmpty())
            return -1;
        return entry1.get(0).compareTo(entry2.get(0));
    }
```

This will put the null elements in the end of the array, and the empty lists before them.

Comment: mmh don't like the fact that two null elements will be sorted in a different order depending on which one goes in the first argument. if both are null or empty you should return 0

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing 2 arrays but you don't check if comparing object exists...

```
int max_generations = 20;
static ArrayList<Integer>[] population = new ArrayList[max_generations];

Arrays.sort(population, new Comparator<ArrayList<Integer>>(){
        @Override
        public int compare(final ArrayList<Integer> entry1, final ArrayList<Integer> entry2){
            Integer value1 = entry1.get(0) == null : -1 ? entry1.get(0);
            Integer value2 = entry2.get(0) == null : -1 ? entry2.get(0);

            return value1.compareTo(value2);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case object was:

```
public class Edge {
    private Integer weight;
    public Edge(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

And I call sort for (List edges = new ArrayList<>();) from other class:

```
Collections.sort(edges,(edge1,edge2) -> edge1.getWeight().compareTo(edge2.getWeight()));
```

Here is the result:
[Exception img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxj3U.png)

Solution was to initialize value of object:

```
public class Edge {
    private Integer weight = 0;
    public Edge(Integer weight) {
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public Integer getWeight() {
        return weight;
    }
}
```

and it work!!!
[code 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mu7Qs.png)